# Cannot attach GameObject to a button's On click enviroment within a prefab. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, onclick, gameobject

So I have a prefab which containcs another prefab with a group of buttons. So in one of the buttons I want to attach on the onClick enviroment a gameObject which is in my scene to get its scripts and finally its methods. I can attach just the script but I cannot find the methods of it(They are public). I can't look into the prefab and at the same time at the game object so that I drag and attach into the onClick button. When I click one the other disappears. Any suggestions?

Here is the picture of the prefab that containts the prefab of the group of buttons. Which has the UI Script (that I dragged and dropped) but doesnt have its functions(Public).

[image]

And here is the Canvas(Game object) which has the Script on it (UIManager) that I want the button to get its methods from. But when I click to canvas the prefab dissapears so I cant drag and drop it.

[image]

Thank you...

Comment: Can you post some screens? Your question is not really clear.

Comment: @saeleas sure. second!

Comment: You could try and "lock" the `MainMenu` prefab using the lock icon in the upper right corner of the inspector tab. Then you can drag the canvas without the prefab disappearing. Still, I don't think you can attach a scene object to a prefab script.

Comment: yeah wont work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Inspector tab label and select Add Tab -> Inspector.  Drag the second inspector below the first.  Click on your first object, and then click on the little padlock icon in the upper-right of the first Inspector.  Now click on the second object.  You can now drag-and-drop things between Inspectors.

You can attach objects to the instance in the Hierarchy, regardless of the Hierarchy instance being a prefab.  You may want to approach this with some thought as to what constitutes a prefab (read: template) and what is just an object living in the Hierarchy.

You can't attach Scene objects to the prefabs in your Assets.